# Button custom view in Fragment

Tags: android, xml, button, layout, fragment

I have a layout in a fragment where buttons were created dynamically every time. The numbers of button that I have to create is the lenght of a particular array. So I can't create a static XML layout, but I create an XML layou with only 1 button with visibility gone and I want to use its layout by findviewbyID and change its visibility.

I can not use find view by id to link my button with the id of the XML button. How can I do it?

Part of code.

```
for (int y = 0; (y < 3) && (i <= items.length); y++) {
                final Button item_button = new Button(getActivity());
                item_button.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.item_button_layout);
                item_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                TableRow.LayoutParams par = new TableRow.LayoutParams(y);
                item_button.setLayoutParams(par);
                int id = i;
                item_button.setId(id);
                item_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int btn_selected = item_button.getId();

                        Fragment fragment = new ItemPageFragment();
                        if (fragment != null) {
                            FragmentManager fragmentManager = myContext.getSupportFragmentManager();
                            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
                            fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        }
                    }
                });
                a.addView(item_button);
                i++;
            }
            layout.addView(a);
```

XML layout

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/item_fragment_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/item_layout"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/folder"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp"            
        android:background="@drawable/item_button"
        android:drawablePadding="-25dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the "gone" button in your Layout at all.

1) Put your button in a separate layout.

2) Call Activity#getLayoutInflater() to get a LayoutInflater and inflate programmatically the layout id you specified and cast the view to a Button.

button_layout.xml

```
<Button
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
     android:drawableLeft="@drawable/folder"
     android:paddingLeft="40dp"            
     android:background="@drawable/item_button"
     android:drawablePadding="-25dp"/>
```

Then on your loop:

```
Button button = (Button) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.button_layout, null, false);
... set your click listener
tableLayout.addView(button);
```

Comment: can you explain me more please?

Comment: ok I tried it but there is a red line in getLayoutInflater(). "In fragment cannot be applied to ()"

Comment: Be sure to use the: android.support.v4.app.Fragment package

Answer (score 0):

If someone is interest the solution is:

Button BUTTON_NAME = (Button) LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.BUTTON_NAME_layout, null, false);